# How to list all Docker local registries and delete them and all related images?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have created a local registry using:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

How do I delete this local registry and the images pushed to it?

Comment: Just kill the container, and it'll all be gone: `docker rm -f registry`

Answer (score 0):

`docker --help` gives all available command line operations

`docker rmi --help`:

```
Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images

Options:
  -f, --force      Force removal of the image
      --no-prune   Do not delete untagged parents
```

Using this command with the name of your image will remove it from your local registry

`docker images` will list out all of your local registry images

eg:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
my-app-sample-sample-prod        latest       0b1757ffae22   2 weeks ago     24.1MB
<none>                           <none>       be50d0dc5c6b   2 weeks ago     24.1MB
```

You can use a bash for-loop to delete all images in your local repository, replacing echo with `docker rmi`

```bash
for i in $(docker image list --format "{{.ID}}");
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to delete an image. But is there a way to delete local repository? is it necessary?